# How does starting a bounty affect your reputation besides the amount given for the bounty?

Tags: discussion

This is my first experience with bounty on Stack Overflow. After placing 50 points bounty I got downvotes on my question which for over year was only upvoted. I do not have any claims for that critique. On the contrary, I am obliged. It just made me wonder on how usually reputation changes after starting a bounty - I do not mean here a loss of 50 points (or other amount) for the bounty.

Question to admins - are there any statistics or research on how placing a bounty affects reputation afterwards?

Comment: I'm not sure whether there are statistics on this, but it's important to note that placing a bounty brings more attention (and typically different types of people) -- this doesn't necessarily mean people will view your question positively.

Comment: You get no guarantee whatsoever that the extra attention you draw will produce a positive outcome.  I'd strongly recommend you edit your question and make it obvious that this is in fact a programming question, the first 4 paragraphs don't make that clear.

Comment: I do not regret losing those few points. Neither do I not need to be informed that I can loose some points to whatever reason. I posted this question to find out if there is any research on what happens to reputation after starting a bounty. For example, within 7 days after starting a bounty 40% users received up-voting on bounty question, 10% did not received any voting, and 50% received down-voting. Anybody looked on that figures?

Comment: You might search one meta.se, where I [found this for you](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36146/how-much-additional-rep-does-a-bounty-question-usually-earn/36147#36147)

Comment: With old questions, bumping them is risky since they might be off topic these days. Yours is clearly off topic and your bounty remark says it all: "Looking for complete tool with VBA code" - Stack Overflow got a close reason exactly for this: *Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead*